# настроить "Поделиться от Яндекса"

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

есть страница с блогом как настроить "Поделиться от Яндекса" на каждый пост, сейчас делится самой страницей о блоге

Answer (score 2):

[Документация](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/add-docpage/) гласит, что за url-адрес, которым надо поделиться отвечает атрибут `data-url`

Следовательно, добавьте его в разметку:

```
<div class="ya-share2" data-url="https://site.ru/page/" ...
```